# Whats the cleanest way to get mod_xsendfile installed on debian lenny

Tags: linux, debian, debian-lenny

I would like to get mod xsendfile installed on my debian lenny server but I can not seem to find a deb anywhere not even on backports

When installing from source : http://tn123.ath.cx/mod_xsendfile/ it seems the installer gets a bit angry when trying to muck around with apache conf files.

I can kind of get this all to hand together, but was wondering are any clean steps to get xsendfile installed on apache?

(Side question: is there a reason its not in the mainstream repos - is there something inherently unstable about it?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package is in squeeze/sid, just install libapache2-mod-xsendfile after adding either repo to your /etc/apt/sources.list.

I dont know why it wasnt included before. Its not in stable atleast, that much i know.

EDIT:

I dont have the rank to edit other users posts  but here goes Sam.

If you want to use dpkg -i to install the package you will have to download the [individual package](http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/libapache2-mod-xsendfile), choose architecture and download.

example:

```
dpkg -i libapache2-mod-xsendfile_0.9-2_i386.deb
```

I suggest adding squeeze or sid to /etc/apt/sources.list and then use apt (will download, install and satisfy any dependencies for the package):

```
apt-get install libapache2-mod-xsendfile
```

If you want to use apt-pinning use something like this in your /etc/apt/preferences

```
Package: *
Pin: release a=stable
Pin-Priority: 700

Package: *
Pin: release a=testing
Pin-Priority: 650

Package: *
Pin: release a=unstable
Pin-Priority: 600
```

This will cause stable to be of higher priority than testing(squeeze) and unstable(sid) and thus use stable as default when downloading packages with the apt tools.

Comment: you will still need to add this to your http.conf file (apache configuration)
To do this, if you are in ubuntu, 
cd /etc/apache2/ and
sudo nano apache2.conf
then:  sudo service apache2 restart
XSendFile On
add the following at the end: 
XSendFile On

Answer (score 0):

You should follow artifexs advice but you should be careful when adding the unstable/sid repository to your apt configuration! Packages from unstalbe7sid will override the ones from stable/lenny when doing an apt-get upgrade. You should use [apt pinning](http://wiki.debian.org/AptPreferences#Pinning) to downgrade the priority of unstable/sid. Otherwise you will run into troubles during your next upgrade.

Comment: since this is now the top google answer, perhaps some instructions with dpkg -i would be better ...